# Как получить количество изменений между двумя коммитами в Git?

Tags: git

У меня есть commit A и commit B. Я хочу получить статистику сколько вставок и удалений было между этими коммитами.

Типо с A по B было 1000 вставок, 100 удалений.

Comment: `git diff --stat A B`  не работает?

Comment: Да работает, спасибо!